# Session auto-exchange between many users [ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net, session

I used a custom SessionWrapper class for handling Session in my ASP.NET project. It seems ok but I have recently found that it has hilarious error. If many user login to my website, their session will be exchanged or mixed. User A will has session of User B and maybe User C has Session of User A. It may change after User refresh the page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class SessionWrapper
    {
        public static string USER_SESSION = "userSession";

       public static void SetUserSession(string email, Dictionary<int, DateTime> products)
        {
            UserSession userSession = new UserSession() { Email = email, Products = products };
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Add(USER_SESSION, userSession);
        }

        public static UserSession GetUserSession()
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_SESSION] != null)
            {
                return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_SESSION] as UserSession;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static void RemoveUserSession()
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_SESSION] != null)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(USER_SESSION);
            }
        }
    }

    public class UserSession
    {
        private string email;
        private Dictionary<int, DateTime> products = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

        public string Email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Dictionary<int, DateTime> Products
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a two questions
1. How do you determined that the sessions are mixed? I mean how exactly do you check it?
2. Do you store instance which you got from the wrapper?

Comment: In fact, I use more than two different laptops for testing at the same time. When a User log-in, the Email display on the page has changed (SessionWrapper.GetUserSession().Email). I'm not sure about your second question :(

Comment: I found the reason, because I used OutputCache tag in ASP.NET (and something went wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason apart from some strange code in application like Jonas H noticed is that you are testing it in either **one browser instance in separate tabs** or **two instances of the same browser**.

Try display the HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID to determine whether you are in the same session in all cases.

Comment: I found the root of this error :( Because I used OutputCache tag (and I don't know why It caused the Session exchanged)

Comment: That explains everything, have you switched your OutputCache off or set 'vary by' property?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding locking semantics:

```
private static Object locker = new Object();

public static UserSession GetUserSession()
{
  lock( locker)
  {
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_SESSION] != null)
    {
      return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[USER_SESSION] as UserSession;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Locking is unnecessary, the framework will ensure that the session collection is user specific

Answer (score 0):

It's the "static" modifier.  Static variables exist for the lifetime of the AppDomain they were created in.

i.e. the w3wp.exe app process that spawns the app domain that the process itself runs in.  No matter which request it is answering to at the time.

Therefore your static variables can be set by one user, and the read into another users session with how you have this setup.

Comment: There are no static variables in the code except for the name of the session key.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all sessions with the same key: USER_SESSION. You need to provide a unique key for each user (perhaps the email address).

Comment: Session is a unique collection per user, you don't have to vary keys by user. That is the idea for session...

Comment: You're right. Guess I was thinking more about Application not Session.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code should behave as desired. If the problem indeed exists as described, it must be caused by code elsewhere in the application.